Add Opportunity Team Member not showing anything except Add Row, Cancel and Save button
We have a custom profile that is assigned to the users and we are giving the Read, Edit and Create access of the opportunity via the permission set. Also given the CRED access to the Opportunity Team Member to the same user via permission set and added the Opportunity Team Members related list on the Opportunity. Now when the user is accessing the opportunity and clicking on the Add Opportunity Team Member from the related list, the pop-up is being opened but only buttons are visible. Is there something that is getting missed out?


does user have access to Contact (via Account)?  OpportunityContactRole is a junction between Contact and Opportunity

@cropredy
Yes, the user has all the access.
Actually, the Opportunity Team Member layout was not assigned to the user so that was the issue here. I checked everywhere but the page layout on the Opportunity Team Member. It is resolved now.

I should have thought of that; the same issue can occur with the Add Products screen for Opportunity Products, or Order Items. Can also occur for Add Campaign Influence. Took me the longest time to figure it out. You should write an answer for this to benefit the community and after 48 hours, you can mark it as Accepted
